# Javascript filter function not returning array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

function to return array of largest elements from each sub array

---

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
      var max = 0;
      var newarr = [];
      newarr = arr.filter(function(elem) {
          max= 0;
          for(var i=0;i<elem.length;i++) {
            if(max<elem[i]) {
              max = elem[i];
            }
          }  
          return max;
        });
      return newarr;
    }

    largestOfFour([[4, 5000, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [3, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Comment: Note that the title is incorrect. `filter` is returning an array. It's not the array you want, but it is an array.

Comment: you'll want .map instead of .filter - the whole function is as follows `var largestOfFour = (arr) => arr.map(elem => Math.max(...elem));`

Comment: what is the expected output? `[
  5000,
  27,
  39,
  1001
]` ?

Answer (score 4):

That's not really how the `filter` function works. The `function` you pass into `filter` needs to return a Boolean: `true` if the given element should remain in the resulting Array, and `false` if it should be removed. Since you are returning `max`, which is a `Number`, any non-zero value will be interpreted as `true`, and so the element will remain in the Array.

You might try instead writing a `max` function that sorts an Array and grabs the first element (or last, depending on sort direction), then `map`-ing that function over your Array of four Arrays.

Comment: i do not agree for just getting a simple min or max value to sort an array with O(nlogn) in the best case. a single loop with O(n) does work and give the wanted result. in this case for a manual looping, reduce is tool of choice, if not using `Math.max` or it counterpart.

Comment: The point being to write a `max` function; you can optimize it from there all you want.

Answer (score 1):

As erictgrubaugh said, Filter does not work like that,here is the document for you:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(function(val){
  return val >= 10;
});
// filtered is [12, 130, 44]
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness a solution in a line in ES6 with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),  [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and a [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
const largestOfFour = array => array.map(a => Math.max(...a));

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5000, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [3, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below program to find the larget element in all subarrays

```
function largest(arr){
    var out=[];
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        var max=Number.MIN_VALUE;
        for(var j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
            max=Math.max(max,arr[i][j]);
        }
        out.push(max);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` won't do what you're trying to do. It just chooses if the element will be accepted or not.

What you need is `map`. It performs an operation on each element of array.

Here's a solution -

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  
      var newarr = [];
      newarr = arr.map(function(elem){
        return Math.max(...elem);
      });
      return newarr;
    }

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5000, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [3, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

Comment: why `...elem` but no other ES2015 constructs?

Comment: exactly what the question asks for @tanmay ... an array of maximums